# Confused about how to use wp_enqueue_style

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I've read the updated codex about using `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `@import`. I'm a newb and just flat out confused how to use this.

My theme is athletica and my child theme is athletica-child. Do I use those name somewhere in the `wp_enqueue_style` code? I'm not sure what text in the code needs to be replaced, if any:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'athletica-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('athletica-style')  );
}
```

Also, I've seen warnings about if your parent themes use `wp_enqueue_style` in it's functions.php file. Mine does!

Now what do I do?

Comment: Did you register these styles with wp_register_style() first?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: "Also, I've seen warnings about if your parent themes use wp_enqueue_style in it's functions.php file." Can you colaborate on this. What are the specific issues regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_enqueue_style is a MUST to add your styles according to codex. But you don't need to use your child or parent theme name anywhere.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>
```

The first param $handle could be anything, doesn't matter what you put here. I can see you have used your theme name in there, it acts as an identifier so you can use anything. But, make sure they are unique in all cases. For example, if you use like:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'athletica-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'athletica-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('athletica-style')  );
```

Here the handles are same, so you will see one of those css is added, not both.

I think you are familiar with other parameters of this function.

Note: It is not mandatory, but always a good practice to register the style using [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) function.